# Program to join TS videos using command line

Tags: windows, command-line, video-editing, recording

I have a need to join .ts video files.
I know of http://www.ffprojects.net/tssplitter/ which works very well, but as far as I can tell it is GUI only.

I need to be able to do this from the command line in Windows.  Are there any solutions out there that can handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[ffmpeg for windows](http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/)

```
ffmpeg.exe -i concat:file1.ts^|file2.ts^|file3.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f vob combined.mpg
```

Comment: Thanks. That works, but the escape character for pipe on windows is ^ not \

Answer (score 7):

I would simply use the command line. Navigate to the folder with all `*.ts`-files to be concatenated and then run the...

```
copy /b *.ts output-file.ts
```

...command, which takes all `*.ts`-files in the current directory and concatenates them to a resulting file called `output-file.ts`. The command might run for several minutes, so don't worry, you can grab a cup of coffee now ;)

(as the `*.ts`-format - "Transport Stream" - is a streaming format, it is possible to easily just "add one file after another" without damaging the data inside)

---

*source: http://tomyeah.com/howto-join-multiple-ts-files/*

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the files with `copy /b *.ts output-file.ts` as mozzbozz suggest.

However, keep in mind if the filenames are not using leading zeros (*1.ts*, *2.ts* ... *9.ts*, *10.ts* ... *99.ts*, *100.ts* ...), the `copy` command will use alphabetic lexical order to concatenate the files resulting in wrong order and output-file.ts will be glitching back and forth (*1.ts*, *10.ts*, *100.ts*, *2.ts*, *20.ts*, ... *9.ts* ... *99.ts*, *999.ts*).

Filename alphabetical lexical order must match the natural order of video clips. This is fixed by using leading zeros:

```
for %i in (?.ts) do ren %i 000%i
for %i in (??.ts) do ren %i 00%i
for %i in (???.ts) do ren %i 0%i
copy /b ????.ts output-file.ts
```