# ffmpeg to join videos

Tags: command-line, ffmpeg, video-editing, recording, video-conversion

I previously learned that [FFMpeg can join videos](https://superuser.com/questions/395508/program-to-join-ts-videos-using-command-line):

However, I am attempting to join recorded over-the-air broadcasts (.ts files), and I believe that minor hiccups in signal quality are causing FFMpeg to have problems joining 95% of these.

The command I use is:

```
ffmpeg.exe -i concat:file1.ts^|file2.ts -vcodec copy -acodec copy -f vob combined.ts
```

The error I almost always get is something similar to:

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer in stream 1: 857442 >= 857442
```

If I join the same exact videos using [TSSplitter](http://www.ffprojects.net/tssplitter/tssplitter.htm) (which is GUI only -- I need CLI), it works without error.

So **my question is**, what can I do to make FFMpeg joing these files better, OR is there an alternative CLI that is better at joining recorded .ts files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with `mencoder`. Generally speaking you can join more files with `mencoder` using the following syntax:

```
mencoder file1.ts file2.ts -ovc copy -oac copy -o combined.ts
```

Answer (score 3):

Try simply;

`cat *.ts > output.ts`

Works for me for most TS files